# Circular pairs from array?

Tags: python, arrays

I can't believe this is nowhere to be found, but: I want all consecutive pairs from an array, including the last element with the first one. I tried:

```
[(a, b) for a, b in zip(list, list[1:])]
```

What is the most pythonic and efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach would be to use modulo to jump back from the last element to the first one :

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n = len(l)
[(l[i], l[(i+1) % n]) for i in range(n)]
```

It returns :

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
```

Comment: upvotes for everyone! This is likely the most efficient way, although, maybe not the easiest to understand immediately.

Comment: not the sexiest, but maybe the fastest solution since it doesn't create temporary lists. In C you would do like this since creating a deque or a list is just annoying.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what are you talking about, Jean? Modular arithmetic is sexy!

Comment: from now on: no `lambda` in answer: I downvote :)

Comment: @EricDuminil one remark: quit python 2 and `xrange`. that's becoming old.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I'm just a Python noobie. But for every Python expert telling me Python 3 is the way to go, there's another one telling me that Python 2 will always be more often used than 3.

Comment: Yay, this will be the question for which I get my first python badge! :)

Comment: I'd like to see noobies like you more often. `range` is less efficient in python 2 but works at least (you could mention: "use `xrange` for better efficiency" for python 2 lovers)

Comment: I have posted an answer that I believe achieves the same objective and faster. @Jean-FrançoisFabre it doesn't have a `lambda` so I'll get a downvote I guess :P This is a nice answer, but not sure it pays off. Did I represent your code fairly, Eric?

Answer (score 10):

you just have to add the first element to the second list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

r = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]+l[:1])]
```

result:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1)]
```

Aside: "pythonic" also means not using `list` as a variable name.

Variant: use `itertools.ziplongest` instead of `zip` and fill with first element (as a bonus, also works with `numpy` arrays since no addition):

```
import itertools
r = [(a, b) for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(l, l[1:], fillvalue=l[0])]
```

Comment: Thanks :) Do you have any idea why this breaks down when I have an array instead of a list? I know they are mostly interchangeable, but not always.

Comment: @John What do you mean by an "array"? A `numpy.array`?

Comment: Yes, if l is a numpy.array this does not work and gives me the first two pairs only.

Comment: @John Because the `+` operator does not concatenate arrays, instead, it results in vectorized addition, broadcasting where necessary

Comment: `+` doesn't work the same for numpy arrays. Let me dig. Ok, you could do `r = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(l, l[1:].tolist()+l[:1].tolist())]` (convert to list to add)

Comment: Use `np.concatenate([arr[1:],arr[:1]])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added a variant which is array-agnostic (and probably a tad faster, but still probably not as fast as Eric answer)

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> x = list(range(7))
>>> d = deque(x)
>>> d.rotate(-1)
>>> list(zip(x,d))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: using `deque` and `rotate` for an actual useful purpose. Rare!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not disputing the coolness of some of these answers but nobody seems to have timed them and, in terms of being "Pythonic", they can get a little obscure compared to just appending or extending the circular part to the end.

```
l = xrange(1, 10000)

def simple_way(list_input):
    a = [(list_input[i], list_input[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(list_input)-1)]
    a.append((list_input[-1], list_input[0]))
    return a


timeit simple_way(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop

def top_rated_answer(list_input):
    n = len(list_input)
    a = [(list_input[i], list_input[(i+1) % n]) for i in xrange(n)]
    return a


timeit top_rated_answer(l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: try `a.append((l[-1], l[0]))` for a potentially even faster answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's giving me the same speed either way

Comment: ok, but it avoids the creation of a temp list. Less characters & same speed => better :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that's true, I will update. I just wanted to demo that no fancy tricks were needed to make this fast (although it does take up a second line though :) ).

Comment: one-liners are sexy but sometimes a good old C-like coding is faster, yes. Even, modulo is costly.

Comment: Deserves more upvotes due to analysis if nothing else.  Want the best way to do something? test!

Comment: @Baldrickk indeed. I realised I had a couple of global references in the tests as I packaged them into functions for testing. I've updated the answer and the approach by Eric has improved more than my simple approach, but it's still appreciably faster to go with the approach that's easier to read.